# How to change the location of .vnc directory

Tags: vnc, vnc-server

As you know, vnc has a work directory called .vnc which is by default located under user's home directory after you installed the vnc server. How can I change its location? Thanks

Change it from ~/.vnc to /opt/mydirectory/.vnc

Thanks

Comment: Is this a good idea? Is `/opt` per-user or per-machine? What documentation is available that says that two copies of VNC running under different users work correctly when they share the same `.vnc` directory?

Comment: Actually, I do not have enough space under my home directory. That's why I want to move the .vnc to another location.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, just change HOME environment variable before starting up vnc.

```
export HOME=/opt/mydirectory;
vncserver
```

This will create .vnc as /opt/mydirectory/.vnc.
I used this trick to use different temporary passwords. It's not a solid solution but just convenient and easy.

Note: on VNC, $HOME is inherited from vnc. You might want to change it back to the regular directory on the vnc session.